# create new object by value as key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to create new object with value as key in javascript.
I have a obj `arrobj`, how to create a object having key and value same

```
function createobj(arrobj){
  var newobj = Object.assign({}, ...arrobj.map(e=>Object.values(e.fields)));
  return newobj
}

var arrobj = [{
  fields: {
   service: "finance",
   country: "SG"
  }
}]


Expected Output
var newobj = {
    finance: "finance",
    SG: "SG"
}
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: `var arrobj = [
  fields: {` - something is not right.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values, and then reduce them to a single object with the values as keys:

```js
function createobj(arrobj) {
  return arrobj
    .flatMap((e) => Object.values(e.fields))
    .reduce((p, c) => ((p = { ...p, [c]: c }), p), {});
}

var arrobj = [
  {
    fields: {
      service: "finance",
      country: "SG",
    },
  },
];

console.log(createobj(arrobj));
```

Comment: good one, though I wonder if shadowing values fn in local scope is the best example, if someone take the line out it would not run and might be hard to track why

Comment: What do you mean exactly @VitaliyTerziev? There's no `values` variable in any parent scope... but yes, it can be better to just chain the reduce

Comment: Ok, maybe I am missing something then - I can call 'values' in the global scope and there is such fn, if you strip the code from the 'createobj' fn it would not work (previous version). Yep chaining looks better indeed.

Comment: You're right! I'm the one missing something, wasn't aware of the global `values` function :)

Comment: fyi - I checked node, then FF and both were missing this fn so I guess it is just debugger helper fn (at least in FF) I wasn't able to find any ref in docs as well .. the code was just fine after all.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your mapping function, so the object values get accumulated to one opject that is returned then:

```js
function createobj(arrobj){
  var newobj = Object.assign({}, ...arrobj.map(e => {
    var acc = {};
    for (let value of Object.values(e.fields)) {
      acc[value] = value;
    }
    return acc;
  }));
  return newobj
}


// Test 1
var arrobj = [{
  fields: {
   service: "finance",
   country: "SG"
  }
}]
console.log("Test 1:", createobj(arrobj));

// Test 2
var arrobj2 = [{
  fields: {
   service: "finance",
   country: "SG"
  }
}, {
  fields: {
   service: "finance2",
   country: "SG2"
  }
}]

console.log("Test 2:", createobj(arrobj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output you are looking for:

```
function createobj(arrobj: any): any {
    var newObject = {};
    Object.values(arrobj[0].fields).forEach(v => {
        newObject[v] = v;
    });

    return newObject;
}
```